# Syntax error escaping string in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server 2012 and have read in lots of places that we only need to escape the single-quote character, by doubling it up. In most cases this seems to work for me, but I am having particular trouble with the following simple stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @SQLStr nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLParam nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLParamValues nvarchar(max)

SET @SQLStr = 'UPDATE test_data SET name=@1,name_reservation_date=@2 WHERE id=@3'
SET @SQLParam = '@1 nvarchar(50),@2 datetime2(0),@3 bigint'
SET @SQLParamValues = '@1=N''b''1'',@2=''2014-4-25 12:09:39'',@3=12345'

EXEC( 'EXECUTE sp_executesql N''' + @SQLStr + ''', N''' + @SQLParam + ''', ' + @SQLParamValues)
```

The error that I am getting is this:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.
>   Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ',@3=12345'.

And the problem is that I am trying to write the value `b'1`, which I have escaped as `b''1`. If I write just `b1` then there is no problem.

The syntax error is on the last line - i.e. when trying to use the `@SQLParamValues` string as an argument to my `EXEC` call.

But I can't see any unclosed quotation mark, can someone help me out? Is there a better approach that I should be taking, to avoid all of these doubling-up of quotes? I've inherited this system from someone else so I'm not entirely convinced at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `sp_executesql` in another `EXEC`. Use the syntax below. Note that the parameters' values are passed without a variable:

```
DECLARE @SQLStr nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLParam nvarchar(max)
SET @SQLStr = N'UPDATE test_data SET name=@1,name_reservation_date=@2 WHERE id=@3'
SET @SQLParam = N'@1 nvarchar(50),@2 datetime2(0),@3 bigint'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLStr, @SQLParam,
    @1=N'b''1',@2='2014-4-25 12:09:39',@3=12345
```